# laravel htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (raw sql count)

Tags: arrays, string, laravel

I am having the following error: `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` when I am executing the following sql statement in laravel.

```
public function index($id)
{
    $event = Task::find($id);
    //$tickremain = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT artists FROM tasks where id='1'"));
    $tickremain = DB::table('tasks')->select(DB::raw('count(*) as thresholdc'))->get();

    return view('buy.index', ['event' => $event],['tickremain'=>$tickremain]);
}
```

My view:

```
<p>No. of Tickets remaining: {{$tickremain}}</p>
```

I want to get a count of a column field but I'm left with that error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{$tickremain->thresholdc}}` to print the count.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this array because $tickremain is an array. htmlentities() format is

```
string htmlentities ( string $string ).
```

So just try to print $tickremain and check whether it is array or not. If it is array just access like

```
$tickremain['thresholdc']
```

(based on array)